# adding a button or menu item to selected contact

Tags: android, button, contacts

Once a user selects a contact on the device's original contact list, there are several application buttons such as of WhatsApp, LinkedIn, etc. I would like to do the same and add a button of my application to allow the user to have additional option that is related to my application. Is it possible and if yes is there any reference or sample code?

Thanks,
  Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intents for this purpose.
When you click a contact implement OnItemSelected metthod in the activity( here contacts)
in that method please create a intent and invoke that intent by either startActivity or startActivityForResult.

Sample code can be available in Professional Android 4 Application Development book. In that book look into application "ContactPicker"

Url for the book is ["http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/1118102274"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118102274)

Comment: Is itpossible to implement OnItemSelected for the device's contacts or I have to build my own contacts folder?